# IE 11 (64bit) redirected to BING and other Home pages after crash-restore.Worked fine before crash

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, crash

Lenovo Desktop IdeaCentre K430, I5 3350, 12G RAM, Windows 8> 8.1> 10
IE 11 worked perfectly until a crash while transferring files between this computer end a Lenovo Laptop, using memory sticks of varying brands and age.

When I finally decided to use the LENOVO built-in diagnostics, restore (saving my data option) all but 2 of my application programs were not recovered at all and I have found it impossible to restore them, without having Win10 remove them all after a reboot. Only the most minor programs remain.

I have attempted unsuccesfuly to remove BING, which I dislike. I located the IE-11 64b in the Windows folder, but it has been replaced or redirected to BING.

There are other issues, but this is the biggie for me.

After saving my files and important personal data, do I need to re-install Win 8 >8.1 >10 and all my dozen programs I use daily? i.e. anti-virus, Adobe Acrobat, Office 360 etc? from scratch?

Comment: Why are you locating the 64-bit version of IE when by default the 32-bit version is normally used.  If you want to reinstall Windows 10 jut reinstall Windows 10 it will automatically activate.  Have you tried changing the default search provider?